# Linq, select a list of the first expired record grouped by container

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table Fruits that looks somewhat like this:

```
FruitID | BasketID | ExpirationDate | OtherColumns
```

A basket contains many fruits and some of these fruits are expired. I'm writing a query that returns a list of all records with a `BasketID` that have a `FruitID` with an `ExpirationDate` that's greater than UtcNow. This is what I have but I'm struggling with the select on the group:

```
var TheExpiredFruits = (from b in MyDC.Fruits
                        orderby b.ExpirationDate descending
                        where b.ExpirationDate < DateTime.UtcNow
                        group b by s.BasketID into TheBaskets
                        select new MyModel()
                        {
                           //here I can't map to MyModel
                        }).ToList();
```

I'm sure I'm not far but I can't quite figure it out. What do I need to change?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be select * from b in MyDC.Fruits? Isn't "MyDC" your context?

Comment: Why do you group them by `BasketID `? you can do it outside query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show details about the most recently expired fruit, you want something like this:

```
var today = DateTime.UtcNow.Date; // lock in UTC date so it doesn't vary during the query
var result = MyDB.Fruits
    .Where(x => x.ExpirationDate < today)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ExpirationDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.BasketID, (key, items) => new
    {
        BasketID = key,
        MostRecentlyExpiredFruit = items.Last()
    })
    .Select(x => new MyModel
    {
        BasketID = x.BasketID,
        MostRecentlyExpiredFruitID = x.MostRecentlyExpiredFruit.FruitID,
        MostRecentlyExpiredFruitName = x.MostRecentlyExpiredFruit.Name,
        HowLongSinceMostRecentExpiration =
            today - x.MostRecentlyExpiredFruit.ExpirationDate
    });
```

And in query syntax:

```
var today = DateTime.UtcNow.Date; // lock in UTC date so it doesn't vary during the query
var result =
    from f in MyDC.Fruits
    orderby f.ExpirationDate
    where f.ExpirationDate < today
    group f by f.BasketID into basket
    let summary = new
    {
       BasketID = basket.Key,
       MostRecentlyExpiredFruit = basket.Last()
    }
    select new MyModel
    {
        BasketID = summary.BasketID,
        MostRecentlyExpiredFruitID = summary.MostRecentlyExpiredFruit.FruitID,
        MostRecentlyExpiredFruitName = summary.MostRecentlyExpiredFruit.Name,
        HowLongSinceMostRecentExpiration =
            today - summary.MostRecentlyExpiredFruit.ExpirationDate
    };
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the idea of locking DateTime.Utc in the query, didn't think of that. I think I figured out my query (see the comment in Arturo's answer) and I'm going to test it soon. I think your code looks good.

Comment: Note that my answer shows the time since the *most* expired item (the one that has been expired the longest). If you want the most recently expired item, change `Min` to `Max`.

Comment: @frenchie, Is my edit closer to what you were looking for?

Comment: Beautiful, this worked like a charm. I'm using Linq-to-SQL to instead of .Last() I had to do an orderby descending and take the first but overall, this is good stuff. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think you should remove the first part of the answer and just keep the second part (after edit) because that's what's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

For each basket you can create a `MyModel` object using the most expired fruit with this query:

```
List<MyModel> TheExpiredFruits = (from b in MyDC.Fruits
                                  where b.ExpirationDate < DateTime.UtcNow
                                  group b by b.BasketID into fruits
                                  let fruit = fruits.OrderByDescending(f => f.ExpirationDate).First()
                                  select new MyModel()
                                  {
                                      BasketId = fruit.BasketID,
                                      Column1 = fruit.SomeColumn1,
                                      ColumnN = fruit.SomeColumnN,
                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: MyModel contains just value types, no lists. And also, I only want the top expired element, hence I needed the order clause.

Comment: @frenchie: So, What you need is for each basket the top expired fruit?

Comment: Because a basket could have several expired fruits but I only want the most recently expired one. BTW, I figured out the query in the select clause: just requery from the group. So for example, in the select clause, I write (from f in fruits where f.FruitID == fruits.Key select f.SomeCol).Single() and I do this for all the values of MyModel(). Update your code and I'll give you the credit for it because the fruit.Key line got me in the right direction.

Comment: No, the edit is incorrect: it should be Column1 = (from f in fruits where f.FruitID == fruits.Key select fruits.SomeColumn1).Single()

Comment: @frenchie: fruits.Key returns the Id for which you groups by (BasketId). GroupBy returns a collections of fruits with the same BasketId (fruits.Key). You can find the top expired element ordering the fruits and taking the first one